# Amazon Elastic BeansTalk deploy to Test or Production Environment automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have configured amazon elastic beans talk to deploy my rails application. I have two environment configured, the first one is the test-env, the second one is the prod-env. The thing is I want to use test-database in the test environment and prod database in the prod environment.

The following command will deploy my rails application for the production environment and it will use production database specified in the database.yml file in case local environment.

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e production
```

How can I achieve that for aws elastic beanstalk ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @eagle28's answer - you should already have an environment variable called `RACK_ENV`. Set that to the name of your environment (as defined by the files under `config/environments/`) and Rails should use the correct database. This is assuming that you've defined your database parameters correctly in `config/database.yml` of course...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Environment Variables. Depending on the environment, the database connection details will be different. In the environment, go to Configuration -> Software Configuration -> Environment variables

In your database connection function (aka: in your code), get those variables as you would with any OS environment variables.